# Blurry Flatpak apps icon on dock (installed from flathub)

Tags: plank, icons, flatpak

Apps installed via flatpak seems to have blurry icons on dock. Right after starting the app, the app icon on dock seems fine but as soon as its loaded it is blurred. I have tested it in vlc and transmission. I have included the images [image](before and after loading) for vlc :

Answer (score 0):

I would love to know this too. elementary aims to ship with flatpak as default, but all my current flatpak apps are blurry in plank (thunderbird,zoom)